# Calculating total ascents greater than 50m

Tags: algorithm

Calculating total ascent is a relatively common GIS problem.

Given a set of height data (eg from GPS, or from draping a track over a DEM), I am interested in calculating total ascents where each individual ascent is greater than (or equal to) 50m, and separated by a descent of 50m.

For example, an ascent of 100m, followed by a 20m descent, and then an 80m ascent would count as one ascent of 160m. Whereas an ascent of 100m, followed by a 60m descent, and then an 80m ascent would count as two separate ascents.

I have searched extensively but haven't managed to find an algorithm to do so. The aim of the methodology is to only include substantial climbs, and ignore small ups and downs in coming up with total ascent.

I am familiar with other methods of removing noise to come up with a total ascent - so I'm interested in a solution to the specific question above, not in alternative approaches, which are well covered elsewhere eg signal processing to remove noise, smoothing, changing sampling intervals etc.

As an example, here is a sample height dataset. It has 4 climbs of 50m+ (70m, 60m, 520m, 80m), for a total ascent of 730m.

[image: Ascents >= 50m]

The raw dataset from the graph is shown as an array below, with the relevant minima/maxima in bold
{**500**,510,500,510,520,530,540,530,540,550,560,**570**,550,530,510,490,470,450,430,410,390,370,350,330,310,290,270,**250**,270,290,**310**,290,270,250,230,210,190,170,150,130,110,90,70,50,30,**10**,30,50,70,90,110,130,150,170,190,210,230,260,290,280,310,340,370,360,390,410,430,450,470,490,510,**530**,510,490,470,450,**430**,450,470,490,**510**,500}

I think the most likely approach is going to involve repeated iterations through the data culling points based on certain criteria, until we are left with only the specific minima and maxima needed for the final calculation.

A larger test dataset in text format can be found [here](https://ozultimate.com/downloads/ascent_test.txt). The final minima/maxima for this set are: [509, 588, 269, 390, 18, 505, 441, 515], and the total ascent is 761m.

Comment: could you make a 3d line and then simplify the line?  It might be even better to plot it as a 2d line, with x as distance and y as height (just like your graph) and simplify it.  I believe there are more options for simplifying 2d vs 3d lines.

Comment: @jbalk - When you say "simplify", which algorithm are you referring to? Simplify might be a different approach to removing the unwanted bits of data. However, I can't think how it will solve the specific problem above?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you already solved it, but here's another solution that approaches the problem from a different (perhaps more direct) perspective. I've also generalized it so that you don't need to assume that y-values are evenly spaced and you can add thresholds based on x distances if you wanted. It also provides an additional way to measure the ascent.

It's broken into two parts: in the first part, we find all possible ascents (`ascent_chunks`), and in the second, we zoom into each `ascent_chunk` and find the values of `actual_ascent` and `approximate_ascent`<--this one is what you're after. `actual_ascent` refers to the cumulative elevation gained in that section--i.e. what your legs would feel.

```
import numpy as np

ys = np.array(your list of elevations)
xs = np.array(np.arange(0, len(ys))) # but xs could be any monotonically-increasing values, not necessarily evenly-spaced
dys = np.diff(ys)
    
# Find the "ascent chunks" -- where we know ascents exist per your definition
ascent_thresh = 50
descent_thresh = 50

# Initialize
this_ascent = 0
max_ascent_elev = 0
ascent_start = 0
prev_x = 0
meets_ascent_criterion = False
# Storage of chunks
ascent_chunks = []
for x, y, dy in zip(xs,ys, dys):
    
    this_ascent = max(0, this_ascent + dy)
    this_descent = max(0, max_ascent_elev - y)
    
    if this_ascent > ascent_thresh:
        meets_ascent_criterion = True
        max_ascent_elev = max(y, max_ascent_elev)

    # We want to narrow down the ascent_chunk as much as possible, so we
    # keep track of the start of the ascent
    if this_ascent == 0 and meets_ascent_criterion is False:
        ascent_start = prev_x
        
    if meets_ascent_criterion and this_descent > descent_thresh:
        ascent_chunks.append((ascent_start, x))
        meets_ascent_criterion=False
        this_ascent = 0 
        max_ascent_elev = 0
        
    prev_x = x
        
        
# Here we artificially add the last possible ascent chunk since we may have
# met the ascent criterion but not the descent; need to check it.
ascent_chunks.append((ascent_chunks[-1][1]+1, xs[-1]))

# Now find the total and approximate ascent for each ascent_chunk
ascents_total = []
ascents_approx = []
for pa in ascent_chunks:
    
    idx_start = np.where(xs==pa[0])[0][0]
    idx_end = np.where(xs==pa[1])[0][0]
    yvals = ys[idx_start:idx_end]
    dyvals = np.diff(yvals)
    
    # Total ascent
    ascents_total.append((xs[idx_start], np.sum(dyvals[dyvals>0])))
    
    # Approximate ascent
    first_positive_idx = np.where(dyvals>0)[0][0]
    new_yvals = yvals[first_positive_idx:]
    max_elev_idx = first_positive_idx + np.argmax(new_yvals)
    
    ascents_approx.append((xs[first_positive_idx + idx_start], yvals[max_elev_idx] - yvals[first_positive_idx]))
    
# Now we check that the last ascent is actually considered an ascent by the 
# definition and remove it if not
if ascents_approx[-1][1] < ascent_thresh:
    ascents_approx = ascents_approx[:-1]
    ascents_total = ascents_total[:-1]
    
print('ascents_approx: {}'.format(ascents_approx))
print('ascents_total: {}'.format(ascents_total))
```

which yields (for your shorter set of elevations)

```
ascents_approx: [(0, 70), (27, 60), (45, 520), (76, 80)]
ascents_total: [(0, 90), (25, 60), (43, 540), (75, 80)]
```

and (for your longer set of elevations)

```
ascents_approx: [(5, 79), (607, 121), (1062, 487), (2093, 74)]
ascents_total: [(3, 98), (605, 177), (1060, 607), (2089, 103)]
```

Each tuple is an ascent; the first value is the x-value (or in your case the index) at which the ascent begins, and the second value is the ascent value itself (what you're after). These results match your expected ones (compare `ascents_approx`).

It is likely that the two loops can be combined--it was just easier for me to break the problem into two. Also not optimized (the `np.where`s should be replaced and no need for `yvals`--but I was lazy).

Comment: This looks like a nicer coding effort than mine, works successfully on the two test datasets, and can also be extended

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a 4 step process should reduce the dataset to the minimum.

1. Remove intermediate points where the data is monotonically increasing or decreasing. This will reduce the set of points to only the local minima/maxima, which will alternate.
2. Remove the first and last points if necessary, so that all pairs of points go from low to high. This will leave an even number of points.
3. Repeatedly cycle through the data looking at sets of 4 successive points (A/B/C/D), and where A<=(B,C)<=D, or A>=(B,C)>=D, remove B&C - but only if the difference between B & C is less than 50m.
4. At this point, the remaining elements after the last actual maximum should have the maxima decreasing and the minima increasing, so repeatedly check if the last two elements have a difference of more than 50m, and delete if not.

Once the data is clean, you can sum the final ascents as the pairwise differences between the remaining points.

A crude Python implementation of the above. I imagine there will be more efficient algorithms!

```
h = 
[500,510,500,510,520,530,540,530,540,550,560,570,550,530,510,490,470,450,430,
410,390,370,350,330,310,290,270,250,270,290,310,290,270,250,230,210,190,170,
150,130,110,90,70,50,30,10,30,50,70,90,110,130,150,170,190,210,230,260,290,280,
310,340,370,360,390,410,430,450,470,490,510,530,510,490,470,450,430,450,470,
490,510,500]

# Step 1 
i=1
while i<len(h)-1:
    if (h[i-1]<=h[i] and h[i]<=h[i+1]) or (h[i-1]>=h[i] and h[i]>=h[i+1]):
        del h[i]
        continue
    i += 1

# Step 2
if h[-1]<h[-2]:
    del h[-1]
if h[0]>h[1]:
    del h[0]

# Step 3
repeat=1
while repeat==1:
    repeat=0
    i=0
    while i<len(h)-3:
        if ((h[i]<=h[i+1] and h[i]<=h[i+2] and h[i]<=h[i+3]
            and h[i+1]<=h[i+3] and h[i+2]<=h[i+3] and h[i+1]-h[i+2]<=50) or
            (h[i]>=h[i+1] and h[i]>=h[i+2] and h[i]>=h[i+3]
            and h[i+1]>=h[i+3] and h[i+2]>=h[i+3] and h[i+2]-h[i+1]<=50)):
            del h[i+1]
            del h[i+1]
            repeat=1
            continue
        i += 1

# Step 4
repeat=1
while repeat==1:
    repeat=0
    if h[-1]-h[-2]<=50:
        del h[-2:]
        repeat=1
        continue

# Finally sum the individual ascents
ascent = 0
while len(h)>0:
    ascent += h.pop()
    ascent -= h.pop()

print(ascent)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking of something like this

```
with sourcevals as (select st_setsrid(st_makeline(array(select st_makepoint(row_number() over()*5,a) from unnest(vals) a)),26920) blah from 
    (select array[500,510,500,510,520,530,540,530,540,550,560,570,550,530,510,490,470,450,430,410,390,370,350,330,310,290,270,250,270,290,310,290,270,250,230,210,190,170,150,130,110,90,70,50,30,10,30,50,70,90,110,130,150,170,190,210,230,260,290,280,310,340,370,360,390,410,430,450,470,490,510,530,510,490,470,450,430,450,470,490,510,500] vals
    ) foo)
select array_agg(st_y(sim) order by st_x(sim)) from
(select (st_dumppoints(st_simplify(blah,10))).geom sim from sourcevals) f;
```

Which returns:

| array_agg |
| --- |
| {500,570,250,310,10,530,430,510,500} |

It doesn't really work correctly if you have a dip at the beginning or end of the track - like the end of your example.  Simplifying a geometry removes vertices within a tolerance in order to smooth it.  There are several algorithms to play with.  Just an idea and possible approach to the problem, not a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt at a python solution.  I test for the height tolerance of 50 in conditions for the first while loop, then delete from the end of the list while the end value is less than the previous value.  For the beginning of the list I delete the first value while the next value is less than the first value. All this is done in the initial while loop:

```
h = [500,510,500,510,520,530,540,530,540,550,560,570,550,530,510,490,470,450,430,410,390,370,350,330,310,290,270,250,270,290,310,290,270,250,230,210,190,170,150,130,110,90,70,50,30,10,30,50,70,90,110,130,150,170,190,210,230,260,290,280,310,340,370,360,390,410,430,450,470,490,510,530,510,490,470,450,430,450,470,490,510,500]
i = 1
while i<len(h)-1:
  if (h[i-1]<=h[i] and h[i]<=h[i+1]) or (h[i-1]>=h[i] and h[i]>=h[i+1]) or (abs(h[i-1]-h[i])<=50 and abs(h[i]-h[i+1])<=50):
    del h[i]
    continue
  i +=1
  while (h[-1]<=h[-2]):
    del h[-1]
    continue
  while (h[0]>=h[1]):
    del h[0]
    continue
>>> h
[500, 570, 250, 310, 10, 290, 370, 530, 430, 510]
```

Comment: Certainly much simpler than mine(!), and seems to largely work for the initial test dataset. However, I've attached a larger dataset (as a text file). I ran your algorithm over that one, and it doesn't work for that one - very different maxima/minima, unfortunately.

Comment: I was hoping I would spark some interest from someone who is better at algorithms.  I also tested it by adding some values into your original sample.  If I add decreasing values  after the start height it doesn't give the correct results.